# Every representation of a finite group is reducible?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, representation-theory

I somehow "proved" that every representation of a finite group is reducible. While I'm fairly sure the error is something silly, I can't seem to place it. Could someone please help me figure out what the problem is?

Here's the "proof":

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $V$ be a (nontrivial) representation of $G$. Denote the matrix associated with $g\in G$ as $T_g$. And let $S = \sum_{g\in G} T_g$.

Note that for every $g\in G$, we have $T_g S = S = S T_g$. Thus, the subspace $W = \text{im}\, S$ is invariant under the action of $G$.

If $S$ were invertible, then $S = ST_g$ would imply $T_g = I$. So $S$ can't be invertible, and consequently $\text{dim}(\text{ker} \, S) \ge 1$. By rank-nullity, the dimension of $W$ must be less than $\text{dim}(V)$, and thus $W$ is a proper sub-representation.

Comment: I thought that an irreducible representation is one that has no proper sub-representation? Wikipedia corroborates this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation

Comment: What you showed is that the subrepresentation $W$ is always reducible (i.e. you can find a proper subspace of $W$ that is invariant under the action by representations of the elements of $G$).

Comment: @mez: That is not standard usage. A module that is a direct sum of irreducible modules is called *completely reducible*, not reducible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$W$ could be the $0$ subspace. For example, take the representation of $Z/2Z$ given by $\{-I,I\}$. Then $S=-I+I=0$.

edit : so actually, what you have shown is that $S$ is zero for any irreducible representation.